# Change Domain to Static IP, SEO Joomla Friendly URL doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, seo

I need to change my web site hosted in temporary web hosting, to Dedicated Server, with test propouse.
I need to test my web site in my dedicated server, but only have WAN IP.

Can I move my website working in (testsite.sitecompany.com) to http://zzz.yyy.xxx.vvv and will Joomla work?

I was testing, but I have problem with friendly URL's.

I review my .htaccess file and is good.
I uncomment RewriteBase in .htaccess
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in php.ini is good.
I make other backup of my site and I downloaded with File Transfer FileZilla.

I notted that my website with static IP works (can I to browse), When  in congiguration.php:

Friendly URL's are disabled
or
Use URL rewriting are disabled.

I need help.

Thank you for your valuable help.

Best Regards
Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

if without friendly urls is working also in the new server this issue can be related to the ".htaccess" file, maybe the new server have problems with the "Options +FollowSymLinks" option. Try adding a "#" at the beginning of that line. ("#Options +FollowSymLinks")